# How to deal with following scenario in QTP?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Login page taking a Email Id and Password.
After login there is Logout option is as follows:

[image]

Here user's first name is displaying. So now QTP is generates the script as below,

[image]

now when I am login from different Email Id and Password at that time how to check the first name is valid or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things here:

1. ***The name of the object*** being *NikunjN*, just rename the object (in the object repository) to something generic (*UserName*). The name (known as *"logical name"*) of an object doesn't effect the test run.
2. ***The object's description***, you don't show the object's description here, it probably includes the user name and this **will** be a problem. You need to inspect the object (using UFT's "object spy") and see what properties you can use which don't change between users.

Comment: But I want to check the name came from database is correct or not?

Comment: Check the First Name in Profile or in data base.

Comment: @user6350775 you can use UFT's DB capabilities to get the name from the DB and then compare it to the value in the web page

Comment: But it's mongoDB is used in back end so how can I configure it?

Comment: @user6350775 UFT supports querying databases via it's [DataBase Output value](http://www.automationtutorial.com/qtpuft/uftqtp-output-values/) feature, I'm not sure if it supports MongoDB.